# Where is TIMSK1 defined?

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I am trying to understand timer interrupts in Arduino.

I am finding a major difficulty in retrieving documentation.

Sources online refer to apparently "magical" constants (like TIMSK1 for example) but I am unable to find where they are defined.

Do they come from some sort of header file?

Is there some reference documentation anywhere?

Comment: it is not a constant, it is a register - a variable mapped to specific memory location where behind it is a MCU peripheral, in this case the Timer1

Comment: Page 112 of the Atmega328P manual defines TIMSK1 https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already answered, but I'd like to fill in some gaps, perhaps.

Those symbols are not magical, they are the names of the processor and I/O registers and values for the bit-fields inside those registers.  As you found, the processor datasheet explains the layout of the I/O registers. This is standard for all microcontroller vendors.

Here's the home page for the Mega328P: https://www.microchip.com/en-us/product/ATmega328p
since the datasheet PDF might change some day. Note that farther down the page there are many very helpful "application notes" that describe how to do things...

How does a C program, or an Arduino script, get the values of the registers and fields? From the vendor supplied header files.  See here for Microchips "packs": http://packs.download.atmel.com

The compiler that comes with the Arduino IDE distribution has included the headers for the boards it supports. They're buried pretty deeply - we go to the datasheet to find the register and field names, not usually to the header files.

For the mega328, the header file is here (macos):   ~/Arduino.app/Contents/Java/hardware/tools/avr/avr/include/avr/iom328p.h

I'm not sure why you said "*(although not explained in full detail)*". There's really not much to it - it just holds a few bits that enable interrupts when certain things happen in Timer/Counter 1.

From the 328P datasheet 01/2015, TIMSK1 is described on page 90 "*All interrupts are individually masked with the Timer Interrupt Mask Register (TIMSK1).*" The register layout is on page 112. And its position within the I/O register set on page 278. A programmer doesn't need more than that! :-)

(I wish I could attach a pdf... it has a big table of the registers, fields, interrupt vectors, DIP pins, ... all generated from that header file.)

Answer (score 0):

After some search I found that in the the ATMega processor manual those constants are named (although not explained in full detail)

One possible location of the manual is:

https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf